# A point measure is radon

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

This is taken from the Chapter 3 of Resnick's Extreme Values, Regular Variation and Point Processes.

Consider a point process with state space $E$ which is locally compact with a countable basis. Let $\mathcal E$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $E$.

For $x\in E$, define the measure $\varepsilon_x(A)=1$ if $x\in A$, $\varepsilon_x(A)=0$ if $x\notin A$.

Now take a countable collection $\left\{x_i,i\geq 1\right\}$ of points of $E$ and define

$m:=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\varepsilon_{x_i}$

Then for any $K\in\mathcal E$ compact, $m(K)<\infty$.

There is something I do not understand, because if I take $E=\mathbb R$, then I can find compact sets with an infinite number of points, so $m(K)=\infty$. Where is my confusion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, of course.  But I think what Resnick means is to make this condition part of the *definition* of a "point measure".  That is, a point measure should be a measure $m$ of the form $m=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \varepsilon_{x_i}$, with the *additional requirement* that $m(K) < \infty$ for each compact $K$.  So, for instance, taking $\{x_i\} = \mathbb{Q}$  isn't supposed to yield a point measure.

Resnick's wording (page 123) isn't very clear, but I think this is the only sensible interpretation.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand better what he is trying to do.